# What is the purpose of adfm.jar file? How to exclude it from build?

Tags: java, ant, jar, oracle-adf

Mine is an adf application. adfm.jar is already available in our runtime environment and hence I don't want it to be a part of the build(ear). Please let me know what is the purpose of this adfm.jar file and how can I exclude it from being a part of the build.

The build process is using ant.
Sample target of my build.xml is -

```
<target name="ear" description="Deploy JDeveloper profiles"
      depends="init">
<taskdef name="ojdeploy"
         classname="oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.ant.OJDeployAntTask"
         uri="oraclelib:OJDeployAntTask"
         classpath="${oracle.jdeveloper.ant.library}"/>
<ora:ojdeploy xmlns:ora="oraclelib:OJDeployAntTask"
              executable="${oracle.jdeveloper.ojdeploy.path}"
              ora:buildscript="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.dir}/ojdeploy-build.xml"
              ora:statuslog="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.dir}/ojdeploy-statuslog.xml">
  <ora:deploy>
    <ora:parameter name="workspace"
                   value="${oracle.jdeveloper.workspace.path}"/>

    <ora:parameter name="profile"
                   value="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.profile.name}"/>

    <ora:parameter name="outputfile"
                   value="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.outputfile}"/>
  </ora:deploy>
</ora:ojdeploy>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

adfm.jar contains the runtime libaries for the ADF Model layer. This consists of
BC4J EJB Client
ADF Model Runtime
BC4J Oracle Domains
ADF Model Generic Runtime
BC4J Runtime
ADF Swing Runtime
JSR-227 API
BC4J EJB Runtime
BC4J Client
BC4J IAS Client

As mentioned these are runtime libraries and you wouldn't normally include them within your application EAR. You don't have to do anything specifically to exclude this jar from your ear file. Jdeveloper deployment works with the concept of deployment profile. When you create a deployment profile for your application, by default none of these libraries would be added to the EAR file.
In your case if you notice the jar file is present in your application, check the library and jar settings in your application deployment profile.

Access the deployment properties from the application Properties

Check [this screenshot](http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_-_01_10_2014___15_34_03-5dGGs1U5.1412174528.png) to see what the window looks like

This lists the libraries that will be included as part of the deployment. **None** of these runtime libraries should be checked, because like you said they are part of the runtime. **Uncheck if any are checked**